# Laravel: Having a Recipe from a DB table pulled based on allergen constraints?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a meal plan generator based on user input constraints.

One of these constraints is allergens. I initially attempted having two tables, Recipes and Recipe_Allergens, as **one recipe can have many allergens,** and connected them by Recipe ID.

E.g. Recipe Table:

| id | Recipe_Name | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lasagna | Dinner |

E.g. Recipe_Allergens Table:

| id | Recipe_ID | Allergen_Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Dairy |
| 2 | 1 | Gluten |

The user input form is all drop down except for the allergens, which is checkbox. That's why the input must be imploded, and then exploded again:

```
$request->merge([
    'allergens' => implode(',', (array)$request->get('allergens'))
]);

$meal = $request->meal_type;
$allerg = $request->allergens;

$allergenarray2 = explode(",", $allerg);
```

I then joined these tables and did a search in order to find the appropriate Recipe ID based on the given user dietary constraints:

```
$recipenew = Recipe::join('recipe_allergens', 'recipe_allergens.recipe_id', '=', 'recipe.id')
    ->where('recipe.type', $meal)
    ->whereNotIn('recipe_allergens.allergen_description', $allergenarray2)
    ->get('recipe.id');
```

Added to a Meal Plan Table:

```
$x = 0;
while ($x < $days) {
    $recipeday = (new Carbon($request->date))->addDays($x);
    $recidnew = $recipenew[$x]->id;
    MealPlanDisplay::create([
        'Recipe_ID' => $recidnew,
        'Day' =>  $recipeday,
        'user_id' => $currentuserid,
    ]);
    $x = $x + 1;
}
```

However, the problem is I get a logic error because of this DB setup. 
This works if the user inputs both "Dairy" AND "Gluten" as their allergies. However, if the user only inputs "Dairy" as their allergen, they will still get "Lasagna" recommended in their meal plan because 'Gluten' and 'Recipe_ID' are isolated alone. This is bad because Lasagna still has Dairy present in the recipe.

What other programming solution is there, to check for each individual allergen in a recipe that may have multiple allergens?

Comment: If you checkbox name attribute is in an array format (`name="allergens[]"`) you will get it as an array in your controller with `$request->allergens`. there is no need to implode/explode. As for the faulty logic, use the relation (more in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the recipes that dont include the allergens, use the relation between the `Recipe::class` model and `Allergen::class` model

**Option 1**

If you dont want to change the structure, set the relation to `hasMany`

```
public function allergens()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Allergens::class, 'Recipe_ID');
}
```

And use the code

```
$recipenew = Recipe::where('recipe.type', $meal)->whereDoesntHave('allergens', function($QBallergens) use($allergenarray2) {
    $QBallergens->whereIn('Allergen_Description',$allergenarray2);
})->pluck('id');
```

**Option 2**

Change your structure for a many to many relation.

So you need a seperate table `Allergens` and a pivot table `allergen_recipe` with allergen_id and recipe_id as keys.

```
public function allergens()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Allergens::class);
}
```

and use "almost" the same code (adapted to ids).

```
$recipenew = Recipe::where('recipe.type', $meal)->whereDoesntHave('allergens', function($QBallergens) use($allergenarrayIds) {
    $QBallergens->whereIn('id',$allergenarrayIds);
})->pluck('id');
```